# Is it relatively accurate to get page view stats from the show action of a rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, analytics

I'm looking for a decent estimate of page views. How accurate is getting page views from something like:

```
  def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @user.profile ||= Profile.new
   @profile = @user.profile
   @user.viewcount = @user.viewcount + 1
  end
```

Google analytics is a last resort.

Comment: Suggest following the "last resort", as it's mature and well tested with plenty of features that doesn't take up your server's resource as it would if you continued with current method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@user.increment(:viewcount)` to hit directly to the DB

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics is great, if you can make it work. This will lag your server, but assuming SHOW is the only method you are tracking pages views it should be fine.

However, for INCREASED accuracy (100% accuracy compared to 0%) try this:

```
 def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @user.profile ||= Profile.new
   @profile = @user.profile
   @user.viewcount = @user.viewcount + 1
   # We want this to save :), or else we would get 0 in our DB all the time,
   # and 1 all the time in our view (?)
   @user.save
  end
```

This should be fine, if you can handle a little lag ( about 1-5 ms, max 7 ms )